# Copy files from multiple directories and paste it into multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell, scp, function

I have a directory " /data/archive

In this directory there are 8 different subdirectories.

```
eg : /data/archive/a
/data/archive/b and so on
```

Files under these subdirectories have date appended to their names so I'm copying files only for the date I need.

Currently what I'm doing is this :

```
cd a
scp *20210826* user@server:/data/20210826_inputfiles/a
cd b
scp *20210826* user@server:/data/20210826_inputfiles/b
```

Is it possible to code it in a way that I don't have to move through each directory one by one ?

Any help on this would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible - write a loop

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious is:

```
for dir in a b b d e f g ; do
    cd $dir
    scp *20210826* user@server:/data/20210826_inputfiles/$dir
    cd ..
done
```

(I added the `cd ..` because that would seem logical to me)

You can also put it in a script. That will need some rethinking:

- do you want to give the date as an argument to the script?
- do you want to have the script determine the direcories by itsself, or have them hard-coded in the script?

et cetera.

Comment: `scp "$dir"/*20210826* ...` would be more logical than changing directories at all